# Is there any automation for formatting text in PowerPoint

Tags: formatting

We usually use PowerPoint for formatting slide decks of our clients where maximum time and effort goes in textual formatting like Headings, sub headings, bullets sizing using Master slides. Is there any way using Macros or any other code or script that  helps us in reducing these efforts.

Comment: Are styles and templates not an option? Why do you need Macros or scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Teach your crew and clients to use a template.

Then all the styles can be updated pressing a cuple of buttons.